# How many Pokemon are there in Pixelmon 3.0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

How many Pokemon are there in Pixelmon 3.0?

Comment: The question in itself lacks serious research. Have you tried reading the Pixelmon page on the Minecraft Forums?

Answer (score 7):

There are currently:

## 807

available Pokémon in Pixelmon. You can use **[this page](http://pixelmonmod.com/wiki/index.php?title=Available_Pok%C3%A9mon/Progress)** to keep track of update progress.